# Is there a simple expression for the coherent information of a Pauli channel?

Tags: quantum-information

The coherent information of a channel $\Lambda$, with complementary channel $\Lambda_c$ is defined as:

$I(\Lambda)=max_{\rho} \{ S(\Lambda[\rho])-S(\Lambda_c[\rho])\}$

I have noticed that it seems to be a common assumption for general pauli channels that the expression for the coherent information can be simplified to:

$I(\Lambda)=1-H(\Lambda)$

Is this true? What is the proof? Where was this first demonstrated?

Thanks!

Comment: Where have you noticed this (can you give a reference)? Also, what do you mean by $H(\Lambda)$?

Comment: By $H(\Lambda)$ I mean the entropy of the Choi matrix. So in the case of a Pauli channel $H(\Lambda)=-\Sigma P_i Log(P_i)$

A couple of the places it seems like this is assumed to be true are:

[here](http://arxiv.org/abs/0708.1597)

[here](http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.98.030501)

[and here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_capacity)